# Synchronization from mobile to server

Tags: sql, html, sqlite, mobile, synchronization

Hye there im going to develop a web system for my final year project using html5 but i am a bit confusing on how am im going to synchronize from the mobile to the server... is there a way to synchronize from mobile (SQL lite) to Administrator(SQL server)... kindly help me regarding this matter

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific about what your "mobile web system" is.  A regular browser doesn't have access to a SQL Lite database so when you say HTML5, I presume you're talking about something other than a regular browser.  Browsers can do AJAX calls to send or retrieve data from a server.  Other environments may have additional capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization can start of simple, but quickly can get rather complex. It all depends on your needs.

Ask yourself the following questions:

- do I need to handle deletes? - tombstones/delete flag
- is sync one-way or two-way? - backup/copy vs full sync
- does anything take more than 100ms a second to save? - date/time issues, or need for overlap
- can a record be edited on two devices (or a device and the server) at once? - conflicts

The simple solution is to just use a "lastModified" field and keep track of where you were up to. Remember to use the date/time of the system running the database, so on the device get the current UTC date/time of the server, then get all updates <= to that date/time. Just query for all records since that are newer than you saved date and copy them to the other server.

The more complex solution tracks deletes, handles transactions (started before sync, finishes after sync, missed by simple solution), has advanced conflict resolution, supports batching, etc.

To be even safer you want to stop using date/times and have a global counter for your revisions. This gets even trickier if you want to track updates that have started but not committed their transaction (look at SQL-Server Change Tracking, `CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()`).

More details can be found on [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992) as one example of how it is done.